# CS5Ox Pset4 Recover: code only recovers partial images

Tags: c, cs50

I have some semi-working code for CS50 Pset4. If you run it you will see that it recovers 27 jpg files but only the first couple of lines are visible.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef uint8_t BYTE;

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // ensure proper usage
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: ./recover infile\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // open file to be recovered
    FILE *infile = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if (infile == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not open infile.\n");
        return 2;
    }

    // temp storage for blocks
    BYTE buffer[512];

    // variable to store filename
    char filename[8];

    //store number of recovered files
    int n = 0;

    // temp storage for outfiles
    FILE* outfile = NULL;

    // iterate over all blocks of memory until end of SD card is reached
    while (fread(buffer, 512, 1, infile) != 0)
    {
        // read one block
        fread(buffer, 512, 1, infile);

        // check if block is start of jpeg
        if (buffer[0] == 0xff && buffer[1] == 0xd8 && buffer[2] == 0xff && (buffer[3] & 0xf0) == 0xe0)
        {
            //close previous file if already open
            if(outfile != NULL)
            {
                fclose(outfile);
            }

            // creeate new outfile
            sprintf(filename, "%03i.jpg", n);
            outfile = fopen(filename, "w");

            // write block to outfile
            fwrite(buffer, 512, 1, outfile);

            n++;
        }
        else
        {
            // write block to current outfile
            if(outfile != NULL)
            {
                fwrite(buffer, 512, 1, outfile);
            }
        }
    }

    //close last outfile
    fclose(outfile);

    //close infile
    fclose(infile);
}
```

Comment: Your `filename` is too short (null-termination?). Spending multiple hours on it...well, a bit wasteful.

Comment: @Eugene, per the specification file name should be XXX.jpg. Considering the null-termination i would think i need 8 chars to store the filename. Or am I missing something obvious? (i started cs50 with 0 prior experience :) )

Comment: @Mark, you can find an example of my output here: http://imgur.com/3Nf1Ui4 . I don't have any idea of what the output should look like but it should be a clear picture.

Comment: I was wrong about this one, sorry. Miscounted the characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see several things that could be causing that problem.

First, check the order of your `n` counter. The counter should be added before you actually start writing on the new file, but that's just a matter of preference, and how clean you want your code to be.

Secondly, try to substitute your `else` condition with the following code:

```
if(outfile != NULL)                          
      {
        fwrite(buffer, 512, 1, outfile);
}
```

**Note**: Please bear in mind that I've substituted your `else` condition for an `if` condition. This is due to the fact that when the first `if` condition is met, then it executes this condition and 'jumps out of the block'. So the `else` will be executed only the first `if` condition won't execute.
If you wanted to keep your `else` condition, then you should have to nest another `if` , as you've done in your code.

By substituting that `else` with an `if` that will always be checked regardless of the value of the first 3 bytes of your jpg (that is, regardless if they're 0x00, 0xff, 0x00), you will obtain a much clear and understandable code.

Lastly, and more important: why are you writing twice to the same file in the same operation? Pay attention to the `fwrite()` function below your `n++` counter. Is it really necessary?

In other words: delete this line:

`// read one block
        fread(buffer, 512, 1, infile);`

Other mistake, is that you're reading your file twice, and advance twice in every step, so you will get half information.
This is the reason you're getting half of the images (27 or so).

Erase these two lines:

`// read one block
    fread(buffer, 512, 1, infile);`

As I've said, by reading and writing twice within your files, you get half of the information. This leads to that fuzzy way in which you're getting your images all colored in senseless colors (I guess) and half of the image files.

I've run `check50 2016.recover recover.c` with your code and with the fixed solutions I've just provided you and it passes all the checks from CS50's check50. Take your time and think about everything in your program, including the control-flow, which is an important part of it, as well as the pointers usage.

Starting CS50 without any prior experience can be daunting. Keep it up. You've already made it almost into Week 5.

Comment: Thanks Togeri! This has been really helpful. I didn't realize that the fread in my while loop condition also advanced the pointer. Changed my code and passed check50. On to week 5! :D